# PhpStorm: multiple projects on the same directory

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

When I want to work on e.g billing, I open billing files and close the others, and when I want to work on other area I have to open files and close other files, which are all from the same directory

Is there a way to make multiple projects on the same directory? I used to do this Sublime Text,

Can I do this in PhpStorm?

Comment: What kind of problems do you have when working in one project? Why it needs to be separate projects?

Comment: I spend a lot of time opening sets of files and closing others.

Comment: How about defining scopes in the preferences? You can then choose the scope in the project view

Comment: Use **contexts** -- `Tools | Tasks & Contexts` for editor tabs (your "sets of files") .. and **Scopes** (`Settings | Scopes`) for Project View panel. Does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your source folder as a content root for multiple projects:

- create a project somewhere (empty)
- add your sources location as a content root to it (Settings/Directories, Add content root)

You can create as many projects as you like this way... But I'd really suggest trying scopes and contexts, as suggested by @LazyOne